# Solving $x \cdot \lfloor x \cdot \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor = 11$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Solve $x$ for $x \cdot \lfloor x \cdot \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor = 11$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes value of greatest integer not exceeding $x$.

I can't find out whether this has a solution or not.

Comment: Hint: start by proving that $2\le x<3$.

Comment: I've edited your question: watch out with notations, like $x[x]$, it resembled enormously a notation like `x[3]` in informatics where `x` is an array and you're taking the third (or even the forth) element of that array. I've added multiplication marks for clarification.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of brute force is okay here...

Clearly, $2< x< 3$ and so $4\leq [x[x]]\leq 9$

In the event that $[x[x]]=4$ then for $x[x[x]]=x\cdot 4=11$ that would mean that $x=2.75$.  Does that work?  Well, $[x]=2$ and $x[x]=5.5$ and $[x[x]]=5$ which is not $4$ so no, this case fails.

In the event that $[x[x]]=5$ then for $x[x[x]]=x\cdot 5=11$ that would mean that $x=2.2$.  Does that work?  Well, $[x]=2$ and $x[x]=4.4$ and $[x[x]]=4$ which is not $5$ so no, this case also fails.

You can continue in this fashion checking $[x[x]]=6$ or $7$ or $8$ or $9$ as well, but for these you would have $x<2$ which fails even more spectacularly.

Final conclusion: no such $x$ exists such that $x[x[x]]=11$